# Match two columns in r of different csv and print the matching keyword in the column with respected category

Tags: r, match

---

I've two different csv files File 1 with Keywordscolumn and File 2 with Keywords and category column. I'm looking forward to match the keyword file (File 1) with the keyword column in File 2 and if it matches it should print the category(column in File2) of the keyword matched.
eg:

File1

```
#Keywords       
HDFC        
Insurance        
Patym      
BookMyShow
```

File2

```
#Keywords(Column)     
SBI Bank      
Insurance     
Paytm         
BookMyShow   


#Category(Column)         
Bank          
Insurance      
Wallet        
Entertainment
```

what i'm looking forward is to finding out a solution to match the Keywords column of different csv and if the keyword matches it should print it along with the respected category.

Comment: You can check `?%in%` and `?match`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
KeywordsFile1 <- c("HDFC", "Insurance", "Patym", "BookMyShow")
KeywordsFile2 <- c("SBI Band", "Insurance", "Patym", "BookMyShow")
Category <- c("Bank", "Insurance", "Wallet", "Entertainment")

Category[KeywordsFile1 %in% KeywordsFile2]
[1] "Insurance"     "Wallet"        "Entertainment"
```

**EDIT:**
To obtain also keyword you can use this code

```
key.match <- KeywordsFile1 %in% KeywordsFile2
cbind(KeywordsFile1[key.match], Category[key.match])
```

Comment: So how should look your desired output?

Comment: I think the name of the matching keyword is desired as well... which you can simply `cbind` to the category vector

Comment: @Adela first file 1 and file 2 are separate csv files. File one has keywords and file 2 has categories of the keywords. So if the keyword column of file1 matches keyword column of file2 it should print the keyword that matched along with the category of the matched keyword.